# javascript to hide multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div all start with `expense`. I am able to hide them all with below formula

```
$("[id^='expense']").hide();
```

But I have a requirement to exclude one of the div start with `expense`. This one will change depends upon other functions so I can not change the name.

Is there anyway I can exclude a specific one( for example `expense_one`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using not you can do this:

```
$("[id^='expense']").not('#expense_one').hide();
```

**Update:** id is specified using #

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to hide all divs divs that has id starting with expense and then show the div you want on the next line. keeping it simple

```js
$("[id^='expense']").hide();
$('#expense_one').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expense_x">1</div>
<div id="expense_y">2</div>
<div id="expense_one">3</div>
<div id="expense_a">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just try with below code

```
  $("[id^='expense']:not(:first)").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can exclude `elements` from wildcard selector. Inside `not` you can pass elements separated by commas . If you want to exclude only one specific element just put only those `id` inside `not` .

```js
$("[id^='expense']").hide()
$("[id^='expense']:not(#expense_one,#expense_two)").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expense_one">1</div>
<div id="expense_two">2</div>
<div id="expense_three">3</div>
<div id="expense_four">4</div>
```